# Fluentd: Not able to pipe Rails log to Fluentd STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, fluentd

I'm following this [Fluentd post](http://www.fluentd.org/datasources/rails) to setup a working version of Fluentd with Rails. My `fluent-logger.yml`:

```
development:
  fluent_host: "localhost"
  fluent_port: 24224
  tag: "foo"
  messages_type: "string"
```

The `application.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :info
config.logger = ActFluentLoggerRails::Logger.new
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
```

My `td-agent.conf` directives looks like this:

```
<source>
  type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match foo>
  type stdout
</match>
```

When I start my rails server, I do not see any log messages getting piped to td-agent.log . I'm using the act-fluent-logger-rails gem.

However, when I use the fluent-logger gem in the rails console and execute these commands:

```
require 'fluent-logger'
Fluent::Logger::FluentLogger.open(nil, :host=>'localhost',:port=>24224)
Fluent::Logger.post("fluentd.test.follow",{"from"=>"A","to"=>"B"})
```

I'm able to see the STDOUT getting populated with the message I sent. Where am I going wrong here, with running it in the app? Any heads up on this would be great! TIA.

Comment: Does the td-agent.log get any log messages when you do something on the rails app?

Comment: Yes, it worked after I did a system restart. The logs started aggregating in `td-agent.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Rails app was an API. In that case you may have to set `config.lograge.base_controller_class = 'ActionController::API'`.